# the meaning of MeanSquaredErrorMetric type in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, rmagick

I'm trying to understand the meaning of metric type "MeanSquaredErrorMetric" used in "compare_channel" method of Rmagick, but I do not see a document that explains the meaning of this metric type.

Please help explain for me? Thanks so much.

```
diff_img, diff_metric  = img1[0].compare_channel( img2[0], Magick::MeanSquaredErrorMetric )
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "Comparison Statistics" section on [this page](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/).